# UIScrollView: Keyboard dismiss interactively

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, notifications, uikeyboard

[image]

In the above image the top bar is a custom view which I used like whats app application. Keyboard will dismiss interactively with UIScrollView. I have implemented `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` to move up and down that view. Now the problem is as I used keyboard will dismiss interactively so when user drag his finger to keyboard, it start move up or down accordingly. But I am not able to get any kind of notification to move up or down the view as well.

Comment: Use UITextField's delegate method for Keyboard show and hide.

Comment: @Rushi Which delegate method you are talking about?

Comment: u solved? I've the same problem

Comment: No.. :( I changed to dismiss from dismissInteractively

Comment: @MassimoPolimeni you solved?

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/AndrewBoryk/ABKeyboardAccessory

Answer (score 4):

While I was searching on this matter, I found three different approaches to achieve this. 
The easiest is by attaching that custom bar as an input accessory view https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview

You can also attach a dummy view as an input accessory view which emits information about its current location, as described here: https://github.com/brynbodayle/BABFrameObservingInputAccessoryView

Other, the least favourable is to hide the keyboard without any animations and show a captured keyboard static image animating instead, as described here: https://medium.com/@superpeteblaze/ios-custom-keyboard-dismissal-with-swift-9b6df2d9cc49

Answer (score -5):

The keyboard follows the dragging touch offscreen, and can be pulled upward again to cancel the dismiss.

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
```

see the Documentation `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive`

hope its helpful

Comment: Bro I don't want to dismiss the keyboard like that. I need some information `onDrag` method

Comment: The problem arise because of this `. Interactive`. I need solutions. Anyway thanks for your help :)